# bot discord repite

Tags: python, discord.py

tengo un bot de discord qué funciona a traves de un comando y el problema esque cuando escribo el comando el bot repite siempre lo mismo, cómo podria evitar que suceda esto?

Este es mi codigo:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
 
 
@bot.command()
async def botfn(ctx,   *, palabra):
        
                with open('bots.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    for line in f:
                        if palabra in line.split():
                            await ctx.send('That is the correct spelling for '+palabra)
                            break
                        else:
                            await ctx.send(palabra + " is not in our dictionary")
            
           




@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")


    
 
bot.run('')
```

Aquí dejo una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias antemano!

Comment: Se repite porque estás recorriendo cada línea de tu archivo y por cada vez que no hay coincidencia envías un mensaje. Lo suyo es enviar el mensaje luego de recorrer todo el fichero y no por cada línea. Para ello podrías usar un *flag*, algo como `encontrado = False` y luego, después de recorrer el fichero,  consultar el estado del *flag* para enviar un mensaje u otro. Dentro del bucle `for` sólo vas a cambiar el valor de encontrado a `True` sí y sólo sí la palabra se encuentra en el archivo. La condición `else` estaría demás dentro del bucle `for`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/552904/bot-discord-repite#comment977328_552904), el problema es que cada vez que no existe una coincidencia estás enviando un mensaje al servidor. Por ello el `bot` repite el mensaje.

```py
@bot.command()
async def botfn(ctx,   *, palabra):
    with open('bots.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            # recorro el archivo lina a linea
            if palabra in line.split():
                await ctx.send('That is the correct spelling for '+palabra)
                break
            else:
                # si la palabra no está en esta linea envío un mensaje
                # pero como no se sale del bucle, se repite el proceso para
                # las lineas siguientes, una y otra vez hasta conseguir la palabra
                # o finalizar las lineas del archivo
                await ctx.send(palabra + " is not in our dictionary")
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Mi propuesta es simple, usar un [`flag`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag) que te permita tomar una decisión de acuerdo al valor del mismo. En este caso, puedes decidir enviar un mensaje basado en si la palabra ha sido encontrada o no, en cuyo caso simplemente vamos a cambiar el valor del mensaje a ser enviado.

Por ejemplo:

```py
@bot.command()
async def botfn(ctx,   *, palabra):
    encontrado = False
    message = f"{palabra} is not in our dictionary"
    with open('bots.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            if palabra in line.split():
                encontrado = True
                break;
    if encontrado:
        message = f"That is the correct spelling for {palabra}"
    await ctx.send(message)
```

De esta forma, el mensaje a enviar se determina al finalizar de recorrer el archivo, ya sea porque se han acabado las lineas del mismo (no se ha encontrado la plabara) o porque hay alguna coincidencia.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.